# Why my computer producing too much sounds from CPU and lag very badly when I play games?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory, cpu, gaming

I have analyzed my pc performance by speezy. I wanted to show you the pic but its saying I need 10 reputations to post a pic. I am cpy pasting the whole thing. Just go through.

Operating System -------> Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

CPU ------->  AMD Athlon 7750    57 °C
          Kuma 65nm Technology

RAM ------> 4.00GB Dual-Channel DDR2 @ 401MHz (5-5-5-18)

Motherboard------> ASUSTeK Computer INC. M2N68-AM SE2 (AM2)  74 °C

Graphics --------> W1642C (1366x768@60Hz)
               512MB NVIDIA GeForce 9400 GT (XFX Pine Group)    56 °C

Storage ------> 232GB Hitachi HDT721025SLA SCSI Disk Device (SATA)  37 °C

Optical Drives -------->  HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH22NS50 SCSI CdRom Device

Audio --------->  Realtek High Definition Audio

These are the full info. The motherboard producing 75 degree heat. Is it the real problem I am having huge lags while I play games? But except games all programms run smoothly without any problem. And while I play game , my CPU also produce a huge amount of ear-crashing sound. Whats the problem and what to do to ride over this problem?? Help me please.

Comment: You think is it the main problem?

Comment: check the BIOS version and update it to latest version from this link: http://www.asus.com/in/Motherboards/M2N68AM_SE2#support

Comment: CPUs do not make noise. Just an FYI. You might try listening to exactly where in the case the sound is coming from if you meant the case / computer box.

Comment: The sound is coming from the Fan.

Comment: Replace the fan.  Your CPU is overheating and being throttled because the heat sink fan is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noise is not from CPU but from cabinet fan. Check if the fan screws are loose as it may result in vibration which will make noise.

Lag in the system may be because of the CPU overheating. Take it out and clean it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Gaming is highly CPU intensive and when the CPU is working hard it generates more heat and the CPU fan speeds up to compensate. If the fan and the heatsink are clogged with dust and fluff it makes a lot more noise. The fan and heatsink probably need a good clean and everything will return to normal.